# Python. Прошу совета с парсингом веб-страницы - результат парсинга конкретного URL - "402 Payment Required"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Есть простой скрипт:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.drive2.ru/'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Если url = 'https://www.drive2.ru/' то результат работы скрипта:

```
<html>
<head><title>402 Payment Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>402 Payment Required</h1></center>
<hr/><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Пробовал другие других сайтов - выдает нормальный HTML. Проблема конкретно с этим сайтом: https://www.drive2.ru/

Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Опыта в парсинге почти нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте заголовок `User-Agent` к Вашему запросу (а точнее — измените его). Видимо, сервер фильтрует запросы и отклоняет стандартный заголовок библиотеки `requests`.

***Пример:***

```py
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло)))

Comment: @RomanDenisov Рад помочь :) Если ответ помог Вам, Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на галочку слева.